# Flutter 1.0 - Unable to load text asset

Tags: flutter

I'm having some trouble loading text assets in flutter (1.0).
This is the current code attempting to read the asset.

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    final file = File('$path/toon_test_3.json');
    bool exists = file.existsSync();
    if(exists){
      return file;
    } else {
      // Load the default file
      final newfile = await getFileData('toonRepo/data.json');
      return file.writeAsString(newfile);
    }
  }
```

loadString will failing popping up the following:

```
Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart': <source not available>.
```

If execution continues the following exception is raised:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: toonRepo/data.json)
```

I've tried a lot of solutions here that revolve around the asset section in pubspec.yaml

```
name: hello_world
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  assets:
    - toonRepo/

  uses-material-design: true
```

Am I going wrong somewhere very silly? 
Cheers for any pointers you have.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgwaK.png)

Here is a temporary copy of the code if you want to take a peek. 
[Github](https://github.com/DylanHobbs/TempFlutter)

And here's a stack trace

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
Unable to load asset: toonRepo/data.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:67:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:56)
#3      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:284:23)
```

Comment: What is the path of the `data.json` file exactly relative to `pubspec.yaml`. Is it `toonRepo/data.json` or `assets/toonRepo/data.json` or somethin else?

Comment: toonRepo/data.json. 
It's in the project root. I've added a picture of the structure in case i'm being an even bigger idiot than usual.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Aye, no joy with the clean i'm afraid.

Comment: What if you add the full file path in `pubspec.yaml` instead of only the directory?

Comment: Same error, unable to load asset popping from the `asset_bundle.dart`
I've tried this across andoird and ios emulators also.

Comment: Is above `pubspec.yaml` exactly like you have it in your project or did you shorten it?

Comment: It's copy pasted from the editor. I removed the generated comments and ran it before posting and got the same results.

Comment: out of ideas . .

Comment: I've popped it on github if anyone cares / is board enough to see if it's not a PEBCAK issue. 
`https://github.com/DylanHobbs/TempFlutter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset access works fine with the `pubspec.yaml` in your question.

new Text("Name: " + toon.info.name)),

fails because `toon` is `null` because it never got a value assigned.

You could use `new Text("Name: " + (toon?.info?.name ?? 'foo')),` to work around the exception.

If you add

```
widget.storage.getFileData('toonRepo/data.json').then((f) => print(f));
```

to `_FlutterDemoState.initState()`, you'll see that reading the asset works just fine.

Comment: `new Text("Name: " + (toon?.info?.name ?? 'foo')),` will indeed take care of the null issue. 
However `widget.storage.getFileData('toonRepo/data.json').then((f) => print(f));` does not output anything like data. Just the same `Cannot load asset toonRepo/data.json` error is printed to me. 
You're running the code from the github?

Might be some Macbook Pro issue?

Comment: I run from GitHub but changed the asset entry in pubspec.yaml to what you have in your question.

Comment: Aye, I've ran that too and got the same error. Sorry, had changed it to the full path before pushing. Looks like I'll try another machine.